# Old python program no longer works after updating Pi3 to Pi4

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder, raspberry-pi4

OK, I'm reworking this question. I'm using Spyder 5.4.2 and Python 3.11.

I took the sample program from:

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/graph-sensor-data-with-python-and-matplotlib/update-a-graph-in-real-time

I get the following error:

```
In [10]: runfile('/home/pi/BrewPi/SparkfunExample.py', wdir='/home/pi/BrewPi') Traceback (most recent call last):

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec exec(code, globals, locals)

File ~/BrewPi/SparkfunExample.py:6 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/matplotlib/init.py:107 from collections import MutableMapping

ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.11/collections/init.py) reasons.
```

I'm beginning to suspect that my IDE environment is messed up. When I upgraded my hardware, from Pi3 to Pi4, and tried to install libraries to compile my original program, I installed them using the "--break-system-packages" option, because of other issues/reasons. Earlier Spyder/Python development on the Pi3 did not use virtual environments. (Interesting, a long time ago, I did encounter issues with Spyder and virtual environments on my desktop Kubuntu and gave up trying to develop Python code for the Pi.)

Any suggestions other than re-imaging my Pi4 and starting all over again?

Comment: How did you install matplotlib? That looks like an outdated matplotlib version that's incompatible with Python 3.11.

Comment: "When I upgraded my hardware, from Pi3 to Pi4, and tried to install libraries to compile my original program, I installed them using the "--break-system-packages" option" - sounds like the option may have done exactly what the name warns you it can do.

Comment: `dist-packages` indicates packages managed by the OS package manager rather than pip. If you try to update a system-managed package through pip instead of through the system package manager, you're very likely to break things.

Comment: Change line 107 to `from collections.abc import MutableMapping`. That is, add an ".abc" to the end of "collections". [Python 3.10 removed the aliases](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#removed) to the abstract base classes that were in the top-level `collections` module.

Comment: @iforapsy that is coming from a third-party librar